# Scan a QR code with your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch

Tags: iphone, notifications, graphics, camera, scanning

Per [the directions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208843):

> How to scan a QR code with the Camera app
>
> Open the Camera app from the Home Screen, Control Centre or Lock Screen. Select the rear-facing camera. Hold your device so that the QR code appears in the viewfinder in the Camera app. Your device will recognise the QR code and display a notification.
> Tap the notification to open the link associated with the QR code.

What's meant by "tap the notification" above?  Because this results in a picture of the QR code on my iPhone 8.  There's no notification that I see at all.

Comment: 1. Are you taking a picture of the QR code? The instructions don’t say to do that. 2. Are you on iOS 11 or later? 3. Can you share a screenshot of your camera pointed at a QR code?

Comment: no, I'm not taking a picture.  It's an iPhone 8.  Not sure how to grab a screenshot of the camera looking at a QR code, so I'll have to figure that out.

Comment: 1) [Take a screenshot on your iPhone (Apple)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289) 2) [Find the software version on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod (Apple)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201685).

Answer (score 4):

It should float a yellow bracket round a recognised QR Code, with an abbreviated link underneath.
Tap that. It will go to the site in the link.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the yellow bracket above.

Comment: Try another code - try google "QR Code test" which is what I snapped that picture from. Is your iOS up to date? I'm not sure when it was added.